# Movie asking the scientist what should be the color of the pill they have developed, deciding on orange/purple?

Tags: identify-this-movie

There was a movie with following scene (to the best of my recollection):

> Manager: What should be the color of this pill for market, orange or purple?
>
> Scientist: [Delves into the intricacies and complexity of the chemicals/side effects etc. of the pill, pointing out many facts about the pill etc.]
>
> Manager: Orange/purple it is then.

Maybe it was not even orange or purple, but the sentiment is that scientist came up with a lot of facts and reasons why/why not they should/should not choose some color or the other, without giving any hint of color is suitable, where the manager just decides on color X.

Comment: could you remember anyone of the cast?

Comment: @VijinPaulraj : nop, or would have back tracked it in IMDB myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be [Kids in the Hall: Brain Candy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116768/) ? Anti-depressant that effectively cures depression rather than alleviating the symptoms. It is a blue hue in its synthesized state, but it is distributed as an orange pill. An unfortunate side effect permanently locks users into his/her happiest memory, effectively making the user comatose.

Here is the line from the script dialogue:

```
          No, no, this is Dr. Chris Cooper. He's the inventor of the drug.

          Thankyou for inventing a marvelous drug.

          This is Cisco. He's head of marketing.

          We were having a little jam session...

          and we wondered what your thoughts were on orange.

          For what?

          The color of the drug. Duh!

          Well, the actual color of the drug in its nonsynthesized state...

          is kind of a bluish hue.

          Great. So orange it is then?

          Yeah? Okay. Yeah, I think that's good.

          Could we get back to work?
```

Comment: +1 - Great answer, between Advicer and KevinHowell - nice to see some of the script to conclusively prove it.